# After RAM upgrde, Ubuntu 14.04 does work with 2GB but works with 1 GB

Tags: ubuntu, memory, memory-management

I have an Sony Vaio laptop which had 1GB RAM (512MB X 2 ). I wanted to upgrade to 2GB as the laptop supports up to 2GB.

When I tried to use 2GB RAM  on Ubuntu 14.04 32-bit it boots, passes the BIOS screen, reaches the splash screen and the screen is just flickering and nothing happens beyond that, however if I remove any one of the RAM sticks, it works fine.

Debugging tried:

1. Ran memory test and it recognized both slots (2GB) and the memory tests passed without any issues.
2. Each of the memory was tried in either slots, they work fine.
3. I tried cleaning the memory /pin slot and  verified that both RAM sticks are seated properly.
4. The BIOS setting also recognizes 2GB RAM.

Unfortunately googling did not help me and debugging I could find did not solve the issue. Can someone help  me here?

Laptop hardware spec: https://esupport.sony.com/US/p/model-home.pl?mdl=VGNN230N&template_id=1&region_id=1&tab=manuals#/manualsTab

New RAM: [https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B001NGB3M4/](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001NGB3M4)

Comment: Hi @Venki, this site is for programming questions. I think you're looking for [su], so I've voted to close it here.

Comment: Wrong site. You're looking for [ubuntu.se] or [su] instead. This site is for programming related questions.

Comment: Can you boot from a liveCD or a liveUSBpendrive? If that works and is stable then that rules out hardware problems. (sort of a double check on the memory tests).

Comment: @venki are both the RAM sticks of the same type?

Comment: @Hennes. No  i was not able to boot from the  Live CD  too with 2GB. i get the same form of errors. ( flicker in screen).

Comment: @rahul , yes  both the rams are of same type  and same manufacturer  (1GB 2Rx8 PC2-5300S-555-12 and  512 MB 2Rx16 PC2-5300S-555-12)

Comment: i tried increasing the swap  space,  6gb and tried but still it did not work  .... Appreciate any pointers here

Comment: Finally solved !!!. I was not able to  get it to work with  ubuntu 14.04 but  when i installed ubuntu MATE 16.04 it worked.